# How do you find the complex value $c$ for which this complex function f is continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the complex function $f(z) = \frac{ (1/z)^{18} - (1/z)}{ (1/z)  -  1}$

we can see that $f(z)$ is not defined for $z = 0$ or $z = 1$.

My question is for which complex number $c$ does the function become continuous at $1$?

---

Using limits, as $z$ tends to to $0$, $f(z)$ tends to positive infinity. As $z$ tends to $1$ I seem to be get $f(z)$ tends to $0$ which I feel isn't right.

Also, $f(0.999..9)$ $\approx$ $f(1.00...01)$ $\approx$ $17$

$f(0.999..9i)$ $\approx$ $f(1.00..01i)$ $\approx$ $\frac{1 - i}{1+ i}$

I'm not really sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: $c$ does not appear in the definition of $f$.  Where is it used?

Comment: First simplify the task by writing $f(z)$ as $\frac{1-z^{17}}{z^{17}(1-z)}$

Comment: sorry i mean lets say g(z) = f(z) for all values except 0 and 1 and g(z)  = c at z = 1. for which value of c is g(z) continuous at 1